# How to place "input" and "output_wrapper" divs side by side in IPython Notebook

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I would like to put the input and output DIVs of a IPython Notebook cell to be side by side instead of stacked vertically.

I tried shortening the width and floating the DIVs (with custom CSS in `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom.css`), but although the width seems right, the two DIVs are still not side by side.

This is the CSS:

```
.input {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}

.output_wrapper {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does the `custom.css` file show up in the Sources tab of Chrome Dev Tools? In case it does there is probably a problem with the specificity of the selector. As you can see in the Styles inspector of the screenshot, the `<div class="input">` have the selector `div.input` and as this is more specific than `.input`as in the `custom.css` it will be that style that is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthias Bussonier [has the answer here](https://twitter.com/Mbussonn/status/474189448452665344). The crucial addition seems to be

```
div.cell {
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

to the css.

The html cell version that he [posted on the ipython-dev mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2014-July/014282.html) uses a different approach to yours:

```
%%html
<style>
div.cell{
    box-orient:horizontal;
    flex-direction:row;
}

div.cell *{
    width:100%;
}

div.prompt{
    width:80px;

}
</style>
```